# How to create a table that has a tableHead cell that consists of many parts in reactjs / css using material ui

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Perhaps the title isn't descriptive enough. What I need to do is create table that looks like this 
[image]

Basically the "Average" is a merged cell with two "subcells" "height and "width" may be further broken down. However using spans in material  ui does not achieve desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I created a CodeSandBox for you. To view code and how it works [Visit CodeSandBox here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-table-with-split-column-header-c56ce).

Code for the Header of Table in Image

```
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowSpan="2" />
        <th colSpan="2"> Average </th>
        <th rowSpan="2"> Red Eye </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> Height </th>
        <th> Weight </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
```

Comment: Yeah this works, however the question was how to use material-ui's table component in the process.

Comment: can you show me the table component of material-ui ?